# Ways to optimize simple asyncio program where TCP clients are persistent

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-asyncio, python-3.7

Using Python 3.7.4 and the `asyncio` package I'm trying to write an application that should spawn around 20000 (20k or more) TCP clients which then connect to a single server.
The clients then wait for a command from the server (`received_data = await reader.read(4096)`) and proceed to executing it (`await loop.run_in_executor(...)`) then send the response back to the server (`writer.write(resp)`).

After this cycle is completed, I sleep 100ms (`await asyncio.sleep(100e-3)`) in order to allow other coroutines to run.
The 20k clients should never disconnect and should process commands from the server indefinitely.

I'm interested in ways I can change the code to optimize it (barring the use of `uvloop` or directly implementing a `Protocol` since I saw in uvloop's docs this could improve the performance) beyond what it is capable now.

Let's assume that I cannot modify `handle_request`.

For example the `await asyncio.sleep(100e-3)` is especially bothering me, but I had to add it there, otherwise the impression was that no other coroutines ran other than the first one! Why could that be?
Say I remove the sleep (since in theory the other `await`s should allow other coroutines to run), what else could I do?

Below is a minimal example of what my application looks like:

```
import asyncio
from collections import namedtuple
import logging
import os
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)       
should_exit = asyncio.Event()


def exit(signame, loop):
    should_exit.set()
    logger.warning('Exiting soon...')


def handle_request(received_data, entity):
    logger.info('Backend logic here that consumes a bit of time depending on the entity and the received_data')


async def run_entity(entity, args):
    logger.info(f'Running entity {entity}')
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    try:        
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(args.addr[0], int(args.addr[1]))
        logger.debug(f'{entity} connected to {args.addr[0]}:{args.addr[1]}')
        try:
            while not should_exit.is_set():
                received_data = await reader.read(4096)

                if received_data:
                    logger.debug(f'{entity} received data {received_data}')

                    success, resp = await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(handle_request, received_data, entity))               

                    if success:
                        logger.debug(f'{entity} sending response {resp}')
                        writer.write(resp)
                        await writer.drain()

                await asyncio.sleep(100e-3)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            pass
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        logger.warning(f'Connection refused by {args.addr[0]}:{args.addr[1]}.')
    except Exception:
        logger.exception('Details of unexpected error:')

    logger.info(f'Stopped entity {entity}')


async def main(entities, args):
    if os.name == 'posix':
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, functools.partial(exit, signal.SIGTERM, loop))
        loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, functools.partial(exit, signal.SIGINT, loop))

    tasks = (run_entity(entity, args) for entity in entities)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ArgsReplacement = namedtuple('ArgsReplacement', ['addr'])
    asyncio.run(main(range(20000), ArgsReplacement(addr=['127.0.0.1', '4242'])))
```